# power of test contection to significance

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I was thinking about the next problem:
Test A and Test B use the same sample, the same test, to test the same simple hypotheses. Test A has a greater power than Test B. So if a researcher rejects H0 in test B, he is sure to reject H0 in test A.
YES/NO

I do not understand why the answer is NO.
If Test A has a greater power than Test B, and they perform the same test on the same sample, why does it not necessarily mean that the rejection area of Test A contains the rejection area of Test B?

Thanks!!

Comment: Using test A there is a higher chance to rejects $H_0$ when $H_1$ is true. However, given a particular sample, $A$ may fail to reject $H_0$.

Comment: It is possible that when $H_0$ is true, test B rejects $H_0$ and test A don't?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. However, when you run these tests on many different samples, on average the first test rejects $H_0$ more often.

Comment: I can't understand why such scenario is possible.
I concluded that the rejection area of test B is necessarily contained in the rejection area of test A, and I can't think of an example where this does not happen.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).